# $.mobile.changePage is not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I am using `$.mobile.changePage` to transit to main page upon clicking on sub page back element.

When i click the browser back button from sub page on `chrome` browser, instead of main page i can see the blank page, this is the issue i am having. But in other browser, when i click back browser from sub page it will show the main page.

Below is the code

```
if (clickEvent == undefined) {
        $('.header-title', ui.nextPage).click(function (e) {

            $.mobile.changePage($('#MainFirst'), { reverse: true, transition: 'none' });
        });           
    }
```

I tried with `transition: 'true'` ,also not working in chrome.

Please go to the following url http://hmk.ag/u/0065170250 in `chrome` and click "`Recipes`" slide, now click browser back button, you will see the blank page.This is working fine in FF, Safari etc.

I want to show the main page when i click the browser back button from sub page on chrome.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: when using multiple page in one by mobile, don't rely on back and forward buttons from browser. Use the buttons within your app

Comment: @Grumpy Good, since this is working in other browser, customer is asking for this fix in chrome also. Please share any idea you have to fix this.